# Waypoints.js horizontal and vertical in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm writing a parallax website with waypoints.js and skrollr.js
and ran into a problem:

slide1 should scroll normal (vertical) and slide-2 should scroll horizontal once it's triggered (width: 4000px). But I have no idea how to do that. I know the new waypoints.js has horizontal:true but I'm kinda stuck right now. Has anyone an idea?

```
 <section id="slide-1">
                <div data-anchor-target="#slide-1">
                        <div class="Container">
                        <div class="Content">
                            <h2>Scroll this vertically</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </section>
<section id="slide-2">
                <div data-anchor-target="#slide-2">
                        <div class="Container">
                        <div class="Content">
                            <h2>Scroll this horizontal</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </section>
<section id="slide-3">
                <div data-anchor-target="#slide-3">
                        <div class="Container">
                        <div class="Content">
                            <h2>Scroll this vertically again</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </section>
```

Maybe something like:

```
$('#slide-2').waypoint(function() {

//toogle #slide-2 width:4000px  scroll horizontal:true etc.

;});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Waypoint is not to scroll automattically to elements, it is to get notified when the user scrolls to a given element. So if you want to scroll horizontally to slide-3 when the user clicks on slide-2, you'd have to use something else. Maybe you can show what you did with slide-1 to illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: I thought Waypoints could trigger events. I'm using the http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/ demo. 

I don't think that slide-1 will help in any way since all it does is scrolling vertically.